# No entity manager defined for class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I am trying to just display a list. My Supplier and Property list were displaying until I implemented the product list :(

Now I get this error with the Supplier and Property lists but not for the newly added product list:

[image]

Here is my app/config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

parameters:
    sylius.locale: "%locale%"

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.php_bridge
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form:
        resources:
            - 'SonataCoreBundle:Form:datepicker.html.twig'

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    node: /usr/bin/node
    node_paths: [ /usr/lib/node_modules, %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules ]
    filters:
        autoprefixer:
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/autoprefixer/autoprefixer
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            apply_to: "\.less$"
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/less
        uglifycss:
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/uglifycss
        uglifyjs:
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/uglifyjs
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        mapping_types:
            enum: string

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                auto_mapping: true
                dql:
                    string_functions:
                        HS_CONCAT_ADDRESS: AppBundle\DQL\HSConcatAddress

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

# FOS UserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    registration:
       form:
          type: hs_user_registration
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    service:
        user_manager: app.security.user_manager

# Doctrine migration bundle Configuration
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: %kernel.root_dir%/DoctrineMigrations
    namespace: Application\Migrations
    table_name: migration_versions
    name: Application Migrations

# Sonata Admin Configuration
sonata_admin:
    options:
            use_select2:    false # disable select2
    title:                App
    title_logo:           bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png
    # Override default template
    templates:
        show:             AppBundle:Admin/Backend:show.html.twig
        edit:             AppBundle:Admin/Backend:edit.html.twig
        layout:           AppBundle:Common/Admin:standard_layout.html.twig
    security:
            # handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role

#sonata_intl:
#    timezone:
#        locales:
#            en_GB: Europe/London
#        default: Europe/London

# Sonata Block Configuration
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.admin.block.search_result:
                contexts: [admin]

knp_menu:
    # use "twig: false" to disable the Twig extension and the TwigRenderer
    twig:
        template: knp_menu.html.twig
    #  if true, enables the helper for PHP templates
    templating: false
    # the renderer to use, list is also available by default
    default_renderer: twig

# STOF Doctrine Extensions Configuration
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: %locale%
    orm:
        default:
            translatable: true
            sluggable: true
            timestampable: true

a2lix_translation_form:
    locale_provider: default        # [1]
    locales: ["%locale%"]           # [1-a]
    default_locale: "%locale%"      # [1-b]
    manager_registry: doctrine      # [2]

# Sylius Archetype
sylius_archetype:
    classes:
        product:
            subject: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product
            attribute: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Attribute
            option: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Option
            archetype:
                model: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Archetype
                repository: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\TranslatableEntityRepository
                translatable:
                    targetEntity: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ArchetypeTranslation
            archetype_translation:
                model: Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ArchetypeTranslation

sylius_product:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        product:
            model: AppBundle\Entity\Product
            controller: AppBundle\Controller\Backend\ProductController
            form:
                default: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProductType
            translatable:
                targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\ProductTranslation
        product_translation:
            model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductTranslation
            form:
                default: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProductTranslationType

#sylius_resource:
#    resources:
#         app.backend:
#             driver: doctrine/orm
#             object_manager: default
#             classes:
#                 controller: AppBundle\Controller\Backend\ResourceController
#                 model: AppBundle\Entity\Product

# Sylius Attribute
sylius_attribute:
    driver: doctrine/orm

# Sylius Locale
sylius_locale:
    driver: doctrine/orm

# Sylius Translation
sylius_translation:
    default_mapping:
        translatable:
            field: translations
            currentLocale: currentLocale
            fallbackLocale: fallbackLocale
        translation:
            field: translatable
            locale: locale

# Sylius Variation
sylius_variation:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        product:
            variant:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductVariant
                form: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProductVariantType
```

My admin class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use AppBundle\Entity\Suppliers as Suppliers;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\CreateSupplierForm;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class SupplierAdmin extends Admin
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $baseRouteName = 'Admin\SupplierAdmin';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $baseRoutePattern = 'supplier';

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;


    public function setContainer (ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper $showMapper
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->with('Supplier Details')
            ->add('id')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('created')
            ->end();
        if ($this->getSubject()->getType() == 'LPE') {
            $showMapper->with('Property Expert')
                ->add('LpeFirstName', null, array('label' => 'First Name'))
                ->add('LpeLastName', null, array('label' => 'Last Name'))
                ->add('LpeEmail', null, array('label' => 'Email'))
                ->add('ContractType', null, array('label' => 'Type'))
                ->add('regions', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Regions',
                    "multiple" => true,
                    'label' => 'Regions Covered'
                ))
                ->end();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper $listMapper
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('Type')
            ->addIdentifier('name')
            ->add('created', 'date', array(
                'pattern' => 'dd/MM/Y @ H:m',
                'locale' => 'en_GB',
                'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
            ))
            // add custom action links
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'show' => array(),
                    'delete' => array()
                )
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('type', null, array(),
                'choice',
                array('choices' => Suppliers::getTypes()))
            ->add('name');
    }


    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        parent::configureRoutes($collection);
        $collection->add('create', 'create', array(
                '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Backend/SupplierAdmin:createSupplier'
            )
        );
        $collection->add('show', $this->getRouterIdParameter() . '/show', array(
                '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Backend/SupplierAdmin:show',
            )
        );
        $collection->add('delete', $this->getRouterIdParameter() . '/delete', array(
                '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Backend/SupplierAdmin:delete',
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getBatchActions()
    {
        // Disable all batch actions for now
        $actions = array();

        return $actions;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $query = parent::createQuery($context);
        // Default Alias is "o"
        $query->orderBy('o.id', 'DESC');
        $query->setSortOrder('DESC');
        return $query;
    }

    public function preUpdate($supplier)
    {
        $supplier->setDeleted(0);
        return $supplier;
    }

    public function preCreate($supplier)
    {
        $supplier->setDeleted(0);
        return $supplier;
    }
}
```

And lastly my Supplier entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Suppliers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *      name="suppliers",
 *      indexes={
 *          @ORM\Index(
 *              name="supplier_name", columns={"name"}
 *          )
 *      })
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Suppliers
{

    const TYPE_INTERNAL = 'internal';
    const TYPE_EXTERNAL = 'external';
    const TYPE_LPE = 'lpe';

    protected static $types = array(
        self::TYPE_INTERNAL => 'Internal',
        self::TYPE_EXTERNAL => 'External',
        self::TYPE_LPE => 'LPE'
    );

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned":true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", nullable=false, options={"default":"lpe"})
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated", nullable=true, type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="boolean", options={"default":0})
     */
    private $deleted;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Regions")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="supplier_regions",
     *      joinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *              name="supplier_id",
     *              referencedColumnName="id"
     *          )
     *      },
     *      inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *              name="region_id",
     *              referencedColumnName="postcode"
     *          )
     *      }
     * )
     */
    private $regions;

    private $lpe;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->regions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getRegions()
    {
        return $this->regions;
    }

    public function setRegions($regions)
    {
        $this->regions = $regions;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLpe()
    {
        return $this->lpe;
    }

    public function setLpe($lpe)
    {
        $this->lpe = $lpe;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLpeFirstName()
    {
        return $this->lpe->getUser()->getFirstName();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLpeLastName()
    {
        return $this->lpe->getUser()->getLastName();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLpeEmail()
    {
        return $this->lpe->getUser()->getEmail();
    }

    public function getContractType()
    {
        return $this->lpe->getContractType();
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->lpe->getUser();
    }

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->lpe->setUser($user);
        return $this;
    }

    public function setFirstName($name)
    {
        $this->user->setFirstName($name);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->user->getFirstName();
    }

    public function setLastName($name)
    {
        $this->user->setLastName($name);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->getUser()->getLastName();
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->getUser()->setEmail($email);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->getUser()->getEmail();
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $entityName;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function nullId()
    {
        return $this->id =null;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return User
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = strtolower($type);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        if ($this->type == 'lpe') {
            return strtoupper($this->type);
        }
        return ucwords($this->type);
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param string $created
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        if (!empty($created)) {
            $this->created = $created;
        } else {
            $this->created = new \DateTime("now");
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param string $updated
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Set deleted
     *
     * @param boolean $deleted
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDeleted($deleted)
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deleted
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getDeleted()
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
        $this->updated = new \DateTime();
        if ($this->deleted === null) {
            $this->deleted = 0;
        }
        if ($this->type === null) {
            $this->type = 'lpe';
        }
        if ($this->name === null) {
            $this->name = '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function onPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
        $this->updated = new \DateTime();
        if ($this->deleted === null) {
            $this->deleted = 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getTypes()
    {
        return self::$types;
    }

    /**
     * Set entityName
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEntityName($name)
    {
        $this->entityName = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if ($this->getUser() === null) {
            return 'Supplier' . ($this->id !== null ? ' #' . $this->id.'' : '' );
        }
        return (string) ($this->id !== null ? '#' . $this->id.' ' : '' ) . $this->getUser()->getEmail();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is in your configuration file

```
doctrine:
[...]
    orm:
[...]
        mappings:
            AppBundle:
                type:      ~
                dir:       "Entity"
                prefix:    "AppBundle\Entity"
                is_bundle: ~
```

If it is not working, look over your namespaces, I think (but not sure) it should be like `PROJECT\BUNDLE\Entity` and not just `BUNDLE\Entity` (for both `namespace` and `use` statements)

Comment: You're on the right track, seems the issue is I have some entities that are defined by annotations such as the example above and some extending the sylius models that are xml in a doctrine directory. Seems the presence of that directory stops the rest of my entities being mapped. Can you specify both or is it a case of of use one method and sticking to it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your doctrine configuration to add your bundle to the ORM :

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: '%database_host%'
    port: '%database_port%'
    dbname: '%database_name%'
    user: '%database_user%'
    password: '%database_password%'
    charset: UTF8


  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    entity_managers:
      default:
        mappings:
          ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
          SonataUserBundle: ~
          FOSUserBundle: ~
          **YourBundleNameBundle**: ~
```